# How to set argument to Ninject binder regarding on request header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, inversion-of-control, ninject.web.mvc

Problem:
I have webapi serviss where almost every user has its own database instance to connect. So i have to set different `connection string` for each user. To recognize user i will pass specific Token into header. Regarding on this Token, system has to build and set differenct connection string into Data Access layer constructor (Order in this case)

Question:
Is it possible to pass argument to `Ninject` or any kind of IoC binder regarding on request header?

```
    IOrders _orders;
    public HomeController(IOrders order)
    {
        _orders = order;
    }
```

Here is an Ninject binding, but as you can guess, `HttpContext.Current` is null.

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        var some_value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("Token");
        kernel.Bind<IOrders>()
            .To<Orders>()
            .WhenInjectedInto<HomeController>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("Token", some_value);
    }
```

Maybe there is much elegant way to do this using `Controller Factory` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a service class that does this lookup for you. then inject this service into the Orders implementation.

```
public interface IRequestContext {
    string ConnectionString {get;}
}

public class HttpHeaderRequestContext : IRequestContext {
    public string ConnectionString {
        get {  
            var token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("Token");
            // .. lookup conn string based on token
        }
    }
}

public class Orders : IOrders {
    public Orders(IRequestContext ctx) {
        // create new connection w/ ctx.ConnectionString
    }
}
```

using this method, the lookup of headers and connection strings is abstracted away from the implementation. this makes it easier to test and easier swap out with a different method of obtaining a connection string if the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing Dave approach, i realized that i could solve this `connection string` injection by feeding `HttpContext.Current` into `Ninject` binding like this:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IOrders>()
            .To<Orders>()
        .WhenInjectedInto<HomeController>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("smth", x => {
            var token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("Token");
            var _db = new SomeDataCxt();
            var connStr = _db.DbStringRepository.GetByToken(token);
            return connStr;
        });
    }
```